# How can I get empty columns to appear in SSRS reports?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that groups hours by the environments in which work was executed. Some customers are in all environments (Beta, PPE, Staging, and Production), whereas other customers are only in a subset of environments. If a customer is only in a subset, then there is no column for environments where no work was executed in that section of the report and as a result, there is white space on the right side of that section for each column that is "missing."

Is there a way for me to force the report to list all environments for all customers, even if there is no data for a given environment/customer combination?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a couple of options here.

One is to use a table with a set number of columns for all required environments, instead of relying on the required columns being dynamically generated by a matrix type object, and then filling the columns' values with appropriate conditional expressions, e.g. for the *PPE* column use something like:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Environment.Value = "PPE", Fields!MyValue.Value, Nothing)
```

The other option is to change the Dataset to always return a row for each environment, i.e. if you're getting the data from a T-SQL query you'd use something like `Environments` as the base table and `LEFT JOIN` it to all the required value data, i.e. always returning each `Environment` row even if no values exist. This way you could still use a matrix to dynamically generate your columns.

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! I can't believe I never even thought of managing the columns manually and then using formulas to populate the sums. This was perfect, and improves my ability to format my reports dramatically! Thank you so much, very appreciated!